# Failed to execute command: node @nestjs/schematics

Tags: nestjs

when i  generate new module in nest js cli with command

nest g module book

i get the following error

Failed to execute command: node @nestjs/schematics:guard --name=book --no-dry-run --no-skipImport --language="ts" --sourceRoot="src" --spec

[cli screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMI0B.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is a current bug being looked into right now](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/1693). For the moment, you should be able to downgrade to `8.2.6` and it *should* work until there's a resolution